# Remove specific headers before redirecting to a url?

Tags: node.js

I want to redirect to another url before removing specific headers in Nodejs

```
function removeheaders(req, res, next) {
    res.removeHeader('header-name');
    next();
}
app.get('/url',removeheaders,(req,res)=>{
    delete req.headers['header-name'];
    res.redirect('/hat2');
})

app.get('/url2',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.headers);
    res.send({
        status:200,
        message:"Welcome to home",
        answer:console.log(req.body)
    })
})
```

I tried above code but req.headers is same in url2 as as set in url1.Is there any way we can remove headers before redirecting to another url

Comment: you can't control what headers the client sends when it follows the redirect, it's making a new request outside of your servers control based on you passing it a new url saying 'go here instead'. what are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: @TZHX i am trying to redirecting it to Amazon pre signed url which is containing does not allow authorization header in its req. It says we cannot assign two authorization headers. ````Only one auth mechanism allowed.Signature query string parameter or the Authorization header should be specified````